# Make Routify use #hash

Tags: svelte, routify

I'm using this Svelte router - https://routify.dev/

It works fine but I can't get it to work with hashes instead of regular paths.

In the examples I've changed the nav to `["./#index", "Home"],` and it changes the address bar but the router no longer reacts to the change.

I'm very new to Svelte and Routify so I wouldn't even know where to start from. There isn't much in the Docs either. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [in this post](https://routify.dev/blog/routify-2#hash-based-routing) you just need to change your router component tag to `<Router config={{useHash: true}} {routes} />` in the src/App.svelte file.

All of the links that use the [url helper](https://routify.dev/docs/helpers#url) will automatically get the hash.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Took me a while to get it to work until I found out it was only available for v2.0 beta :)